# Splitting an audio MP3 file

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, mp3

I would like to split an audio file into smaller parts using NodeJS. I would then like to retain the smaller parts as separate audio files. Can anyone recommend a viable approach with relatively low computational time?

Comment: I am  asking for a solution for the problem of splitting an mp3 file in node, I am not asking for recommed a tool.

Comment: Can you explain me this negative points?

Comment: Most likely it was because of this question being the [subject of a topic on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222327/failed-audit-4118533-close-votes-review-queue) -- often it brings the attention of a post to large amount of people and this can result in a lot of up/down votes. Also your question was probably closed because it appeared from what it read that you were looking for a specific module to do this.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks, I don't agree with the motives of closing my question. I was looking for a way for solving my problem. I made a comment about modules, but the objetive of this question is to find a way of splitting mp3 files in Node.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could probably use ffmpeg. It is command line based, which is great since it is accessible, but subprocesses can sometimes die. Here is a node interface that abstracts ffmpeg usage out of command line calls: https://npmjs.org/package/ffmpeg

Your final commands, in the command line would probably look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:30:00 half1.mp3
ffmpeg -i long.mp3 -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:30:00 half2.mp3
```

This command states:

- `-i`: the input file is `long.mp3`
- `-acodec`: use the audio codec
- `copy`: we are making a copy
- `-ss`: start time
- `-t`: length
- and finally the output file name

To handle potentially timeouts/hung processes you should 'retry' and supply timeouts. Not sure how well the error callbacks work. That is do they fail appropriately on a process that hangs.

Comment: I have read about ffmpeg before, but I am using modulus.io to deploy my app, and I am not sure that I can use ffmpeg command line, because I need to install that before using.

Comment: @jvrdelafuente perhaps http://npmjs.org/package/ffmpeg-bin would work. You may be able to get away with just adding that as a dependency and not doing any other other work.

Comment: I canot try that because I am working on windows, and I am not sure witch operative system is using modulus.io. I will try executing that directly on modulus. Can you put an example of use? Because I am not sure how can I mix ffmpeg library with ffmpeg-bin.

Comment: @jvrdelafuente you can get ffmpeg binaries for windows, throw them into a git repo and include that repo in package.json. You could also throw the mac, linux, etc binaries in there too

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your example. `-t` is indeed the length but you provide a timestamp, that means you are extracting 60s from the position `00:30:00`, if you wanted to extract 30s you should use `-to` argument.

Comment: @vdegenne ahh yup, fixing

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [node-lame](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame) to decode an mp3 into raw PCM and then just split the data directly... I can't admit to being an expert on audio formats, but my assumption is that PCM is a fairly naive format without much in the way of bit-twiddling going on, so simply figuring out the percentage of the file that should be in the first section vs the second, and then cutting there should give you two bits of data that you can re-encode using the same module back into mp3s.

Provided the mp3s are constant bit-rate, then you may be able to the same thing with the mp3 file directly. I remember back in the wild-west days of Napster and Kazaa and their ilk that I would have downloads cut off halfway through and I'd be able to listen to half of the song without issue. I don't know how likely that is to work exactly the way you want it to, but worth a shot.

Comment: I want to split a song based on two times. The start time, and the end time. It is possible to use your method to get this objective? Can you put an example? I am not sure, if I have understood you well.

Comment: I don't know if node-lame gives you access to the actual run-time of the song, but let's say you know ahead of time that the song is exactly 3 minutes long, and you want to split the song into the first two minutes and then the last one minute.  Let's say it's a constant bit-rate mp3 and you can just split it directly, without decoding.  You see that the file is, by coincidence, exactly 3 megs.  You could read the file into memory, grab the first two megs of the file and save it, and grab the last meg of the file and save it.  Thereby splitting the song by splitting the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have played around with SoX - a command line tool to manipulate audio. Make sure you build it from the source in UNIX to get MP3 support. And the command you are looking for would be trim.

Here's the official documentation - http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html